# repair Hyperlink.address after moving folder to new location or after saving the file

Tags: excel, vba

On a main spreadsheet column “B” I have a hyperlink for x number of other spreadsheet with data on them. So B1 has hyperlink for spreadsheet 1, B2 hyperlink for spreadsheet 2, so on.
They are all located on the same folder.
On main spreadsheet I have a vba For loop that gets the hyperlink address, assign it to a variable, opens it and copy data from them and paste onto the main spreadsheet:

```
Dim PathFile As Variant
Dim i As Byte
Dim c As Byte
Dim wkb As Workbook

For I = 1 to 10
  PathFile = Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address
  Set wkb = Application.Workbooks.Open(PathFile)

'inner loop that checks cells on main spreadsheet against the cells on the data spreadsheet and copy and paste



'End of inner loop

Next i
```

This code works well but after moving the folder, the  vba code to get the hyperlink.address will not work properly this also happens after I save the spreadsheet. I notice that PathFile before moving the folder will return the full path address of the file but after moving the folder, PathFile will return only the folder with file name and that’s the reason it is not working.

The strange thing is that even after moving the folder, if I hover the mouse on top of cell B1 as example, it will still show the hyperlink with its full path updated to the file correctly. If I right-click the same cell and go to edit hyperlink, the address bar will show only the folder name with the file name.

Is there a way to correct it?

Obs: My previous code was using followhyperlink method to open the files and I had no problem even after moving the folder, but using followhyperlink makes the screen flicker. Yes, I did use:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
DoEvents
```

But the screen still flicker a lot.

Using workbook.open() the screen doesn’t flicker and the code seems to run faster too.

Any advises? Thanks!

Comment: I found a work around the problem:

Comment: By using a IF statement: "if vba.len(Pathfile) < 25 then PathFolder = thisWorkbook.Path" Now I "set wkb = application.Wokbooks.Open(PathFolder & PathFile)" Else I just run the code above.